# How to change TreeItem's underline color in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

> I have a `JavaFX TreeView` which has `TreeItems` with two basic colors , **red and white** . When they are selected they both have `-fx-underline:true` but i have a problem with the line being `Red or White` **i want the `underline` to be always `white`** , is that possible with css in JavaFX ?

[image]

I have tried the below but it doesn't work .

```
.tree-cell-white:selected {
    -fx-font-weight: bold ;
    -fx-text-fill:white; 
    -fx-underline: true;
    -fx-underline-fill: orange;
    -fx-underline-color: blue;
}

.tree-cell-red:selected {
 -fx-font-weight: bold ;
 -fx-text-fill:firebrick; 
 -fx-underline: true;
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken treecells idle color is red, but when they selected you want to them to be white and underlined as well, right?

Comment: @Vanguard Hi :). What  i want is  the underline to be always white. The color of tree-cell text will either be red or white based on style class.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I could not find how to do it by JavaFX CSS, but I found another solution. That is I created `MyTrack` class that derives from `HBox` and added an `ImageView` as an music/mp3 icon and `Label` with text.
Here is a little trick I underlined label by setting its bottom border color and set `MyTrack` as a graphic for `TreeItem`.

```
package underlined.treeview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TreeViewApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        TreeItem<String> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>("Root node");
        List<TreeItem<String>> tracks = Arrays.asList(
                new TreeItem<>(""),
                new TreeItem<>(""),
                new TreeItem<>(""));

        for (TreeItem<String> track : tracks)
            track.setGraphic(new MyTrack("Track"));

        treeRoot.getChildren().addAll(tracks);

        TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
        treeView.setShowRoot(true);
        treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
        treeRoot.setExpanded(true);
        return treeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and `MyTrack` class:

```
package underlined.treeview;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class MyTrack extends HBox {

    public MyTrack(String text) {

        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: aqua;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;");

        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/img/icon/mp3.png")
                .toExternalForm());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setFitWidth(16);
        imageView.setFitHeight(16);

        getChildren().addAll(imageView, label);
    }
}
```

And Voila!!!

[image]

In my example bottom border color is aqua here. Note that `TreeItem` should be instantiated with empty `String`. It was just an example you need to optimize it yourself.

Comment: My whole point is to modify '-fx-underline' to whatever color , no matter the color of tree-cell text. For example I want some tree cells to have white text, some tree cells to have red text BUT ALL THE TREE CELLS TO HAVE WHITE UNDERLINE Color . :)

Comment: Now I got you. You need to change underline color.

Comment: Yes :) my friend.

Comment: By the way I could not find `-fx-underline-color` and `-fx-underline-fill` in JavaFX. Where did you get that?

Comment: I just gave blind shots lol :). In case they work but they didn't.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I have updated my answer, take a look please.

Comment: Wow, beautiful answer. I need to check the memory consumption of it though. I have sometimes 5000 Tree Items and the application  RAM will go 800 MB for fun.

Comment: You found even the same icon. We have a winner here :)

Comment: I don't recommend you to add 5000 TreeItems at first run. Instead you should add them dynamically, i.e. on expand or on scroll by 50 items for instance